# textbox from tcolorbox manual not working!

Tags: tcolorbox

I am currently trying to add some nice textboxes to my current paper. Therefore, I found the `tcolorbox` package and consulted corresponding manual.

Once I browsed through some of the examples and became familiar with the basic usage of the package, I found the example in the manual on page 154 which has an enhanced title box.

The basic code concerning this example would be about (basically copied from the manual):

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}    % Paket für textboxen
\usepackage{varwidth}           % Paket zur anpassung der titelbreite von textboxen

\begin{document}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
    enhanced,
    before skip=2mm,after skip=2mm,
    colback=black!5,colframe=black!50,boxrule=0.2mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm,yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
    varwidth boxed title*=-3cm,
    boxed title style={
        frame code={
            \path[fill=tcbcol@back!30!black]
                ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
                arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
                ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
                arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
            \path[left color=tcbcol@back!60!black,right color=tcbcol@back!60!black,
                middle color=tcbcol@back!80!black]
                ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
                [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)
                -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
                -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
                [sharp corners]-- cycle;
        },
        interior engine=empty,
    },
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title={My title},
    colbacktitle=green
}
\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Sadly, this does not seem to work.

I have narrowed down the problem to the block:

```
boxed title style={
    frame code={
        \path[fill=tcbcol@back!30!black]
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
            arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
            arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
        \path[left color=tcbcol@back!60!black,right color=tcbcol@back!60!black,
            middle color=tcbcol@back!80!black]
            ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
            [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)
            -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
            -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
            [sharp corners]-- cycle;
    },
    interior engine=empty,
},
```

If one removes the both \path branches out of the frame code, it seems to work, but the title box also not coded!

The example should look like:
[image]

Since I did not change anything important from the example code, I do not understand the error message I am getting:

```
Undefined control sequence. [   \begin{mybox}]
Undefined control sequence. [   \begin{mybox}]
```

Comment: This example works out of the box. Please check your version of `tcolorbox`. Current version is 3.94, the feature you're using has been `updated` on 2016-02-26.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, it's a recommendation rather.

The package `tcolorbox` introduced some changes/updates from version 3.80 to `3.90` (i.e. the update from 2016/02/29). The code by the O.P. runs into issues for pre-`3.90` - releases:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\tcb@frame@code ->\path 
                        [fill=tcbcol@back!30!black] ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1m...
l.36 \begin{mybox}
```

Pre-`3.30` versions report following error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/before skip', to which you
 passed '2mm', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.36 \begin{mybox}
```

Any version since `3.90` will provide the correct output, so the easiest recommendation is to update, rather to patch the code here!

[image]

For those who want to compare the errors etc: Here are the older versions of `tcolorbox` [tcolorbox on github](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox)/releases